# Can I make ruby send network traffic over a specific iface?

Tags: ruby, network-programming

I am writing a script that grabs the external IP address along with some other information about each iface. I can't figure out how to make ruby send traffic over a specific iface(eth0 and wlan0 for example). I am currently using the open-uri library to open http://whatismyip.org and read it into a variable.

```
def get_external_ip
  begin
    open("http://whatismyip.org") { |f| return f.read }
  rescue
    return "none"
  end
end
```

Is there any way to specify this at runtime of the script or from within the script itself(ideally)?

Answer (score 0):

You could check this [tutorial on Ruby Socket programming](https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/l-rubysocks/l-rubysocks-a4.pdf). But I doubt that it can be done on a high level like `open`. The interface will be selected normally from the routing table, depending on the destination IP - so maybe it will be easier to fix/adjust your routing table instead.